# What is the principal difference between make command and running build .sh script?

Tags: linux, shell, makefile, build

In this Linux manual is written that [make](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/umake.htm) is:

> a utility for building and maintaining groups of programs (and other
>   types of files) from source code.
>
> Description The purpose of the make utility is to determine
>   automatically which pieces of a large program need to be re-compiled,
>   and issue the commands necessary to recompile them.

What does `automatic determination` mean here? What is the principal/significant difference between running `make` or just running `./build.sh` where I have my build scripts?

Comment: One is a tool that determines what needs to be built based on a Makefioe, the other is a script that does something someone wrote it to do, maybe even using make

Comment: `make` only rebuilds the files whose dependencies have changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the principal/significant difference between running `make` or just running `./build.sh` where I have my build scripts?

`make` can be easily used in such a way that it only rebuilds what needs to be rebuilt (and nothing more than that).

---

#### Comparative example

Consider a project to be built, `program`, consisting of the following files:

```
main.c
foo.c
bar.c
foo.h
bar.h
```

For this discussion, let's assume that `foo.c` and `bar.c` only include (i.e.: depend on) `foo.h` and `bar.c`, respectively.

- With a `build.sh` script which simply consists of commands for building a software like the following:

  ```
  gcc -c foo.c
  gcc -c bar.c
  gcc -c main.c
  gcc foo.o bar.o main.o -o program
  ```

  If just `foo.h` gets modified, this project needs to be rebuild. With this approach, this will be done by re-running `build.sh`, which  compiles **all** the source files. Note, that neither `bar.o` nor `main.o` would actually need to be generated again, since the files `bar.c`, `bar.h`, `main.c` didn't changed and they don't depend on `foo.h` at all (i.e.: they are not affected by a change in `foo.h`).
- With `make` however, if used properly, a dependence graph is generated, so that only the files that need to be updated would be generated again: in this case `foo.c` and `program`.

  That relies on the dependency relationship between the source files and object files (among other things) being properly specified to `make`. This is achieved by means of a makefile:

  ```
  program: main.o foo.o bar.o
      gcc -o $@ $^

  foo.c: foo.h
  bar.c: bar.h
  ```

  Basically, it is explicitly specifying that:

  - `program` depends on `main.o`, `foo.o` and `bar.o`.
  - `foo.c` depends on `foo.h`.
  - `bar.c` depends on `bar.c`.

  ---

  and implicitly:

  - `main.o` depends on `main.c`
  - `foo.o` depends on `foo.c`
  - `bar.o` depends on `bar.c`

  ---

  That way, `make` knows what has to be rebuilt or updated whenever something changes and it updates only that instead of building everything from scratch.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! And what is the idea of `makefile` if everything determines automatically?

Comment: Some relationships of dependency can be determined somehow automatically (e.g.: the `.h` files included by `.c` files), others have to be provided manually.

Comment: If nothing else, Make doesn't know which target in the forest of possible dependency trees is one you want built.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks. Make did actually know which target (`program`), but didn't know *how*.

Comment: `make program` will work without a Makefile if all dependencies are trivial but you want just `make` to do something useful, too.